# My summary information won't show up in Sandcastle using VB ''' syntax

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, documentation, comments, sandcastle

I'm trying to take advantage of [Sandcastle](http://www.codeplex.com/DocProject/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=10744) to help build out system documentation, but for some odd reason none of my `<summary>` data shows up in the chm ... has anyone had success w/ the latest build of Sandcastle and VS2008 using VB?

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked to see that XML document generation is actually turned on (in Build properties) and is creating an XML file in the right place (i.e. bin/Release/)?
Also, see [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/devdocs/thread/055172d5-2e3f-4f51-87af-afab11d4be55/) on MSDN, which documents the same problem I believe.

Answer (score 0):

It is a 2 step process.

- Had to turn on the XML document generation in the project build window.
- Select the generated XML documentation as the project document source in SandCastle UI.