# Why are my comments not included in the .chm generated by SandCastle?

Tags: c#, documentation, sandcastle

My .chm is generated but my comments for classes, namespaces, fields, members are not.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Did you check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562082/my-summary-information-wont-show-up-in-sandcastle-using-vb-syntax) ?

Comment: I was just asking, have you looked at the existing question?  Your original question did not say one way or the other.  And reL "Too many indirections...", huh?  I thought the #1 suggestion was, to make sure you TURN ON XML DOC GEN ?? did you check that?  Is it plugged in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are actually generating the XML file, i.e. that "XML documentation file" is checked and specified in the Build tab of your project properties in Visual Studio, and that Sandcastle knows where to find the resulting file on disk. If you are not making this file, Sandcastle will generate a chm that is properly structured, but contains no comments.

Edit: sorry, now I see that Cheeso's answer points to a message with the same idea. I didn't check the link in the first place because it had negative votes and I assumed it was irrelevant.